# Rails: Form confirm message with data from the submitted form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

Trying to make a custom :confirm message for a rails form that returns data from the submitted form--not just a static string.

```
<% form_for @foo do |f| -%>
<% f.text_field :number_of_bars -%>
<% f.submit :confirm => Are you really sure you want to use ##number_of_bars## bars? -%>
```

The idea is if the user puts in the number 3 in the number of bars text field the confirm message would show up like this: "Are you really sure you want to use 3 bars?"

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.submit :onclick => "return confirm('Are you really sure you want to use '+
          document.getElementById('number_of_bars_id').value + '?' )" %>
```

Replace the `number_of_bars_id` with the id of your field.

If you google a bit you will find a way for this to work with `:confirm`.

Comment: Which JS library are you using?

Comment: just the standard prototype. My javascript skills are not so hot so I tried to stay away from it as much as possible.

Comment: I didn't realize you need the value in form (it should have been obvious to me). I have updated the answer. I am sure there better ways to do this.

Comment: I tested the code and it works for me. You have to replace the `number_of_bars_id` with the correct HTML element id for the `:number_of_bars` field.

Comment: yeah, did that, not so sure why it's not working. It just submits without any confirm box coming up.