# Getting the filename of uploaded file in confirmation popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

I am uploading files with Paperclip. Is there any way of getting the file name of the file that is to be uploaded in a confirmation message?

Something like this:

```
<%= f.submit confirm: "Are you sure you want to upload #{file.file_name}?" %>
```

Is this even possible without using a Javascript-based uploader?

Comment: get the uploaded file name using javascript.. call javascript function on the click of your submit button and show the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367214/1710271). It turned out I needed to add an `onclick` event:

`<%= f.submit onclick: "return confirm('Are you sure you want to upload ' + document.getElementById('file-field').value + '?')" %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
 //call the function and get the uploaded file name
    function GetFileNmae() {
      var oFReader = new FileReader();
      oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file_field").files[0]);
      oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        file_name = oFREvent.target.result;
        alert(file_name);
      };
    };
```

try the above code